# Sharp serializer use a custom object constructor?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

I was looking for a tool able to serialize object instances without a previous mapping.
I'm trying to build a platform able to transform ERP documents from one system to another, using XML formats to match the properties between the multiple systems. 
The problem is that some of the objects instances, do not have a parameter less contructor or a class public constructor, due to permissions and licensing, the new instance of the object is delivered from another managing class, like `ManagingClass.GetNew(ERPDocTypeId)`.

Does anyone know if is it possible using the strategy pattern on the deserializer part of SharpSerializer, which is to use a specific method for the object construction, and then let pass it to the base deserializer?

Comment: I'm a little bit unclear on your problem.  Are you 1) Using `SharpSerializer` and asking how to construct objects with the factory pattern?  2) Using another serializer, and asking how to construct objects with the factory pattern in the same way that `SharpSerializer` supports?  And if #2, what serializer are you using?

Comment: It is option 1). Sharpserializer has an option that allows you to use different construction methods for complex objects, this option is InstanceCreator, which allows you to pass a method where it is possible to carry out the type treatment and call the correct constructor. Meanwhile I've figured out how to do it and I'll put the answer here.